# Flutter custom linter option to ban setState

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, linter, dart-analyzer

I would like to write a new custom linter rule.

Especially, I want to write a rule that forbids the use of the setState function in flutter.

Is there any solution to customize your linter rules out there?

Comment: I have no experience with it, but there is a [custom_lint](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_lint) package that allows creating custom rules.  However, using it requires running a separate command and not the usual `dart analyze`/`flutter analyze` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [certainly do that](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-add-lint-rules-in-flutter/).  But why would you want to ban setState?

Comment: I agree, why would you do that? However, you can't customize the analyzer to do what the question asked via analysis_options.yaml. It would require custom hooks into the analysis server which is much more involved. But again... why would you ban `setState`?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this kind of analysis would require an analysis server plugin. There's is an [API](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer_plugin/doc/api.html) and a [Analyzer Plugin Package](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer_plugin) to do this as well as a view examples of projects using it.

Examples:

- [Dart Code Metrics](https://github.com/dart-code-checker/dart-code-metrics)
- [Built Value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart)